# Could not autowire field: nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gwt

It is a spring boot-project. In the project, I am nowhere using GWT. But I am still getting this error while running the spring-boot project.

```
Could not autowire field: some.package.SomeClass.field
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable
```

Any idea why I am getting this?

Comment: Something on your classpath is referencing IsSerializable from GWT, I'd check the type of `some.package.SomeClass.field` and see what it depends on.

Answer (score 1):

You are pulling GWT in somewhere.  To track this down, you need to look at the classpath your app is using.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ClassPathPrinter
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs();
        Arrays.stream(urls).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

If you are running a flavor of unix (or cygwin), you can also see the classpath as arguments to the java process using *ps*.  Here is an example from an OSX machine:

> ps -ef | grep java
>
> 284:  501 45687 38343   0  6:54PM ??         4:04.20 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:60768,suspend=y,server=n -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed ***-classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar***  -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

One of the classpath entries should be *gwt-user.jar* or gwt-servlet.jar.